# Rails 3 urls with subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I have a rails app that has members that belongs to an organisation.

When members login they now get a url like this

```
www.DOMAIN/organisations/ORGANISATION_ID
```

I want to change this to

`www.organisation_name.DOMAIN` (What do we call a url like this?)

How can I do this?

A small add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Rails 2.3 you will need some plugins, for Rails 3 not. I suggest to watch these screen-casts:
[subdomains in rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3) and [subdomains](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains).

Answer (score 0):

I personally use subdomain_fu, which is great for parsing the subdomain of a request and mapping it to a user account.

You can find it here: https://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu

I'm not sure if it is ready for Rails 3, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have just written an up-to-date brief covering a plentitude of aspects on the subject: http://mines.mouldwarp.com/2012/11/subdomains-in-rails-apps-current-brief.html

It however assumes a fair amount of prior knowledge. The ROR guides and the aforementioned railscasts are thus recommended beforehand.

Comment: Please note that you should post the useful points of an answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted as ["Not an Answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: I'll try to keep that in mind. The question is just too open for a short answer. And the chosen answer is exactly the same, just some links to useful resources.

Comment: @Costa Shapiro I agree. The first comment is a bit harsh. It is important to keep things concise. But, in my mind a link could be a good answer on a question like this. It is a big topic. If your answer came Mar 10 '11 it would have  helped me a lot. Keep it up!